# How to execute specific number of orphan and zombie processes in a single program?

Tags: c++, c, linux, operating-system

I' m trying to write program that executes specific number of orphan and zombie processes. The number of each type of process is defined. I wrote some code, but it doesn't creates the expected output. Expected output means that program should create 15 zombie processes and 17 orphan processes. Meanwhile it 'produces' 17 zombie processes and 17 orphan processes

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define Zombie 15
#define Orphans 17

int main(){

int x;
     
for (int i = 0; i < Orphans; i++){
        x = fork();
  
    if (x == 0) {
               
    for (int j = 0; j < Zombie; j++){
        sleep(5);
        
        x = fork();
        if (x > 0) {
           printf("Orphan process (PID:%i, PPID:%i)\n", getpid(), getppid());
  
           while(1)
                sleep(1);
  
        }
  
        else if (x == 0){
           printf("Zombie process (PID:%i, PPID:%i)\n", getpid(), getppid());
           exit(0);
        }   
         
      }
    
    exit(0);
    }

  }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you using C or C++? Those are two different languages.

Comment: What does "expected output" mean?

Comment: Did you read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and related `man` pages? Did you study for inspiration the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or of [fish](https://fishshell.com/) ? They are open source, and relevant to your question. Are you aware of [daemon(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html)? Did you study the source code of [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/) ?

Comment: @Brian This code is obviously doing the same thing in either language, so while I would probably have just marked it "C," I don't think it's too out of line to include both tags.

Comment: Did you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and read their documentation?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Expected output means that it should create 15 zombie processes and 17 orphan processes. Meanwhile it 'produces' 17 zombie processes and 17 orphan processes

Comment: Well, you have an `if` statement that, if true, prints "zombie" (in the parent process), otherwise it prints "orphan" (in the child process). So, there will always be exactly the same number of processes that print both messages. Pretty straightforward logic. If you wish a different outcome you will need to adjust the logic accordingly, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `for` loop isn't doing anything. Let's refer to the initial process as the grandparent, the children of the first `fork` we'll call the parents, and then the children of the second `fork` as grandchildren. Every time the grandparent creates a parent (17 of them, based on the `for(... i< Orphans...)` statement), that parent has a child (the grandchild), but neither the parent or grandchild make it to the second iteration of the inner `for` loop.

To help make this understandable, let's swap which process is zombie and orphan.

```
int main(){

    int x;

    for (int i = 0; i < Orphans; i++){
        x = fork();

        if (x == 0) {

            for (int j = 0; j < Zombie; j++){
                sleep(5);

                x = fork();
                if (x > 0) {
                   printf("Zombie process (PID:%i, PPID:%i)\n", getpid(), getppid());
                   exit(0);
                }

                else if (x == 0){
                   printf("Orphan process (PID:%i, PPID:%i)\n", getpid(), getppid());

                   while(1)
                       sleep(1);
                }

            }

        exit(0);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

The process who sees `x > 0` is the parent process since the parent receives the `pid` of the child during a `fork`. So this parent should be the one you call zombie. The child sees `x == 0` so it should be called orphan.

Now, when it's the parent, you kill it. When its the child(grandchild), it gets into an infinite loop. So neither parent or its child, the grandchild, make it to a second iteration. So how many parents/zombies are there? Your grandparent process forks 17 times. Each of the 17 parents (children of the grandparent) has one child (a grandchild), then both parent and its child are immediately killed or stuck in a loop. So in the end there are 17 parents/zombies, 17 (grand)children/orphans.

As for how to create only 15 zombies...this question is a little pointless. To start, the outer `for` loop should be using `i < Zombie` so that you create just 15 parents/zombies. Then you just need to make sure one or more of those parents have enough children to create a total 17 orphans. Getting this working is so specific (and as I said, pointless), but with this information, you should be able to get it working on your own.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It seems to be pointless, but it is my homework for Operating Systems class.

Comment: @karatek  You're welcome. Also welcome to Stack Overflow. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. However, there is no obligation to do this.